# jQuery xml find nodes without a specific child

Tags: jquery, xml, find

is it possible to find all nodes that don't have a specified child node?

for example:

**(xml)**

```
<item>
    <name>item 1</name>
    <admin>true</admin>
</item>

<item>
    <name>item 2</name>
    <admin>true</admin>
</item>

<item>
    <name>item 3</name>
    <parent>item 1</parent>
    <url></url>
    <admin>false</admin>
</item>
```

I want to pick out all nodes that don't have a child node "parent". I can do this if I set an attribute named parent and call:

**(jquery)**

```
$(xml).find("item:not([parent])").each
```

but I was wondering if this is possible by using a child node instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may get other good suggestions -- possibly based only on selectors -- but I believe this will work.

```
$('item').filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('parent').length === 0;
}).doSomethingWithTheSetOfItemsWithoutParents();
```

**UPDATE**

Based on [selector documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), I think this one will do what you want:

```
$('item:not(:has(parent))')
```

Comment: thanks for the reply...I forgot to mention that I was able to get it to work with something similar to what you have here, but I was hoping there was a way to accomplish it with selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use jQuery's native [parent() selector](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)?

Comment: I'm actually trying to create a menu system with flyouts. I was trying to set it up without defining the hierarchy of the menus within the DOM of the xml file. Basically, if a menu is a flyout, it has a parent. It starts to get too complicated in the xml if I try to emulate the menu relationships within the DOM structure of the xml file (i.e.trying to select children of children, etc.) With that being the case, I won't be able to use the parent() selector since the actual hierarchy I want in the end isn't necessarily reflected in the DOM.

Comment: I was thinking also in doing it this way, I can reuse items if needed.